# Are Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools still available for download?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am looking for the Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools. Are they still available somewhere?

I can find the [2015](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) and [2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) versions. The 2017 version seems impossible to find.

Due to toolchain limitations, I unfortunately cannot use the 2019 version to install MSVC141.

Comment: https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2017buildtools

Comment: @bhargav-rao Closing this question is inappropriate. You seem to have misunderstood the question. It does not seek any recommendation but seeks help locating essential developer tools. This is most certainly an appropriate question under the Stack Overflow guidelines.

Comment: I think strictly speaking the text in the close reason doesn't match the actual reason (here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which is the "4. Questions asking us to ...find a ... off-site resource are off-topic". Not saying I always agree with that rationale however.

Comment: My thoughts are the same as StayOnTarget's. The problem which I see with the question is that it is asking for a link to a tool, which is off-topic. I was a bit borderline on whether to close this or not, as there [have been prior discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479) where it's been mentioned that asking a link to official docs/tools is ok. However, the number of link only answers that this has attracted, led me to cross the border, & close the question. I'm still across the border, as the [reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/28188876) decided it that way.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is not clear how Microsoft decided not to make VS2017 Build Tool installer an obvious option for you to download, but maintainers on Chocolatey have packed up every recent releases, so you can [download and install from there](https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2017buildtools).

Alternatively, the chocolatey install script contains a link to Microsoft servers where the [VS 2017 Build Tools Installer](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/3e542575-929e-4297-b6c6-bef34d0ee648/639c868e1219c651793aff537a1d3b77/vs_buildtools.exe) is still available.

Answer (score 70):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2022) (guide for installing VS buildtools in a Docker container), I found that you can download:

- 2017: https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe
- 2019: https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe
- 2022: https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe

Comment: Exactly what I needed to fix node-gyp on windows

Comment: The links do not work anymore, they all just forward to the vs_BuildTools.exe setup client

Comment: They are indeed links to the vs_buildtools.exe client, but for each version of VS, so if you run through them, you should see different component versions for things, for example, the 2017 client only has v141 C++ toolsets, while the 2022 one has up to v143.

Answer (score 6):

You can find Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 here.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads

To download any product from the following list, click the download button and log in with your Visual Studio Subscription account when prompted. If you don’t have a Visual Studio Subscription, you can create one for free by clicking on “Create a new Microsoft account” on the login page.

Answer (score 1):

To track it down I had to go to https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads/Featured and search for "build tools" or "build tools 2017". Looks like you'd have to register and sign in to the site to get to the build tools downloads.

Answer (score -1):

YOU CAN DOWNLOAD IT FROM HERE:

**https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15**