# How can i fix this cairosvg error in result to a python code?

Tags: python, svg, cairo, pycairo, svgtopng

Hello I tried running this code:

```
import os
import cairosvg

def convert_svg_to_png(input_folder, output_folder):
    # Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

    # Loop through all files in the input folder
    for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
        # Check if the file is an SVG file
        if filename.endswith(".svg"):
            # Create the input and output file paths
            input_path = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
            output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + 
    ".png")

        # Convert the SVG to PNG
        cairosvg.svg2png(url=input_path, write_to=output_path)
        print(f"Converted {filename} to {os.path.basename(output_path)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Specify your input and output folders
    input_folder = r'C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Underwear - Copia'
    output_folder = r'C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\Grande'

    # Call the function to convert SVG to PNG
    convert_svg_to_png(input_folder, output_folder)



print("FINITO")
```

Having installed:

```
C:\Users\Utente>pip install cairosvg
Collecting cairosvg
  Using cached CairoSVG-2.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cairocffi in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cairosvg) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cssselect2 in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cairosvg) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cairosvg) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cairosvg) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tinycss2 in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cairosvg) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1.0 in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cairocffi->cairosvg) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cssselect2->cairosvg) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.1.0->cairocffi->cairosvg) (2.21)
Installing collected packages: cairosvg
Successfully installed cairosvg-2.7.1
```

But it returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Utente/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/dawdwadwadwadadwadwadwadwad.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cairosvg
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairosvg\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import surface  # noqa isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairosvg\surface.py", line 9, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 44, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found
no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.so.2'
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo.2.dylib'
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libcairo-2.dll'
```

I udnerstand there is a problem locating cairosvg maybe, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: error shows `'libcairo.so.2'` and `libcairo-2.dll` and this means `C/C++ library`. And this is not part of Python. You have to install it separately.

Comment: download on Cairo home page: https://www.cairographics.org/download/

Comment: using Google I found also: [cairo-windows}(https://github.com/preshing/cairo-windows). But I don't use Windows - so I don't know if it can help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

So the problem is that even though I'm pip installing cairosvg, it will install libraries that aren't python but are C7C++ instead?

Moreover, the cairographics download link for windows doesn't exist.

As per the github source, it says it only works on VS 2017, however I don't use VS2017

Comment: problem is that Python module `cairosvg` needs also `C/C++ libraries` but module `cairosvg` doesn't have it and `pip` will not install it. You have to download and install `C/C++ libraries` on your own.When it needs `VS 2017` then it can means itneeds only `compiler` and some libraries without `IDE`. I  in other answers on SO I see it as `Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools`. [Are Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools still available for download? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795314/are-visual-studio-2017-build-tools-still-available-for-download)

Comment: Ok thank you.

I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46265677/get-cairosvg-working-in-windows 

here a guy said: "get a copy of libcairo-2.dll
I did this by installing from uniconvertor-2.0rc4-win64_headless.msi https://sk1project.net/uc2/download/
then look for where libcairo-2.dll was installed to.
say the path is C:\path\cairo\dlls\libcairo-2.dll
in your script add to the top (before import cairosvg)

import os
os.environ['path'] += r';C:\path\cairo\dlls'

import cairosvg should now succeed and work."

However I have some questions:

Comment: 1) "get a copy" means I should copy the libcairo-2.dll installed with pip install cairosvg or should I get a copy of the dll installed using uniconverter? 

2)So installing the uniconvertor will install also cairosvg or should I install cairosvg in addition? (sorry I'm not familiar)?

Comment: `pip` doesn't install `libcairo-2.dll` (author of python's module doesn't add this file in module - and this makes problem on Windows). `uniconvertor` doesn't install python module `cairosvg` (because it doesn't need it) but it installs `libcairo-2.dll` (because it uses directly this library). You may have to copy `libcairo-2.dll` from folder with `uniconvertor` to folder with `cairosvg`. `C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cairosvg`

Comment: Thank you so much for the hassle and the help you're providing furas!

So you reckon I should still pip install cairosvg, then i should install the uniconvertor and replace the libairo-2.dll of cairosvg with the one of uniconvertor; doing so and running the code it shouldn't give me problem right?

I've installed uniconverter, however when i click it it says "gathering required informations..." and it closes. 
Moreover i cannot find the libcairo-2.dll anywhere. here is a photo of pip installed cairosvg: https://imgur.com/a/4ejDsmu

Comment: It is not important if `uniconverter` is working or not. Important is to get `libcairo-2.dll` from `uniconverter` and copy it to forlder with python module `cairosvg` or to other folder which system may uses to search `DLL`. Maybe `uniconverter` installed `libcairo-2.dll` in `C:\Windows\` or `C:\Windows\System32` to shared `DLL` with other programs.